# Compiling pythonnet (.NET) to work Enthought Python Distribution (Canopy) using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: python, .net, visual-studio, clr, python.net

I've built pythonet (python for .NET) using VS2012. All works fine if I just work with plain python. However, once I try to import some of the 'heavier' Python modules such as numpy or scipy, I get runtime errors.

Enthought provided a rapid response with helpful information; to quote the support response from EPD:

> The source of the problem is that the EPD libraries are compiled against VS2008 and they are being loaded using Python compiled with VS2012. Since the EPD dlls do not state the compiler in their manifest files (and some do not have manifests), a dependency on VS2012 is therefore assumed. This results in "an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly".

What I would like to know is whether it is possible for me to built pythonnet using VS2012 so that it behaves as though it were "built against VS2008"?